# Ruby each loop to output A + B + C?

Tags: ruby

Say I have:

```
keywords = [ "lorem", "ipsum", "dolor" ]

keywords.each do |keyword|
  something("#{keyword}")
end
```

Which outputs:

```
something("lorem")
something("ipsum")
something("dolor")
```

How do I instead make it output like this?

```
something("lorem") + something("ipsum") + something("dolor")
```

Comment: You actually want to see the ``+`` sign? Is not a concat?

Comment: Yep. I need the `+` sign.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
keywords.map{ |kw| something(kw) }.join('+')
=> "lorem+ipsum+dolor"
```

Comment: He needs to apply a method to each of the keywords.

Comment: Wow!! Nice one Chen Pang :)

Comment: Just had the idea but I saw your answer. +1

Comment: Same happened here. +1

Comment: A better example would be something like: `def something(str) str.upcase end; keywords.map{ |kw| something(kw) }.join('+')
#=> "LOREM+IPSUM+DOLOR"`.

Answer (score 4):

Simply use [Enumerable#inject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject):

```
keywords.inject(""){ |result, keyword| result += something(keyword) }
```

Simulation:

```
keywords.inject(""){ |result, keyword| result += keyword }
#=> "loremipsumdolor"
```

Comment: I believe you don't even need the initial value ``("")``. This would work: ``keywords.inject{ |result, keyword| result += keyword }``

Comment: How do I make it say `lorem + ipsum + dolor` though?

Answer (score 3):

It seems you actually want to show the '+' sign. Try this:

```
keywords.inject{ |result, keyword| result += ('+' + keyword) }
=> "lorem+ipsum+dolor"
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
keywords = [ "lorem", "ipsum", "dolor" ]
somethings_result = ""

keywords.each do |keyword|
    somethings_result+=something("#{keyword}")
end
```

Comment: @MarkBoulder use konsolebox's solution it's nicer

Answer (score 1):

If `something()` can return an `Integer` or a `String`, you can try this:

```
keywords.map {|keyword| something(keyword)}.inject(:+)
```

If it returns an `Integer`, the code will add the returns numerically.

Comment: This turned out to be the only answer working for my actual code. I'd mark this as correct but Chen Pang's was the first to answer the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you don'y need to call method `something`, you can do the following:

```
 [ "lorem", "ipsum", "dolor" ].join("+")
 => "lorem+ipsum+dolor"
```